# Minor bug with tags tooltips

Tags: bug, developer-story

When I add / remove tags in my developer story fields, the tooltip of the tags doesn't disappear immediately. The tooltip is stuck until I click elsewhere or I mouse enter then mouse leave the tooltip.

[image]

Happens while editing story items and personal tech stack.